# Question about the differential

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Today at class, my teacher stated the following proposition saying it is obvious:

Let $x_0 \in U \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, $U$ open, and $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^m$ differentiable at $x_0$, then for any $v \in \mathbb{R}^d$ we have

$$ D_v f(x_0) = D_f (x_0)(v) $$

It is not obvious to me. Can someone explain to me why this is true? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You mean that the directional derivative can be obtained by multiplying the Jacobian with the direction vector? This is a trivial application of the chain rule (Alexander Chain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first remember what is the meaning of each symbol:

- $D_\nu f(x_0)$ is the derivative of $f$ at $x=x_0$ in the $\nu-$direction, i.e.,
  $$
  D_\nu f(x_0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+hv)-f(x_0)}{h}. \tag*{(*)}
  $$
- On the other hand, we have the following the definition:

*The function $f:U\to\mathbb R^m$, where $U\subset\mathbb R^d$ open and $x_0\in U$, is said to be differentiable at $x=x_0$ if there exists a linear function $A: \mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R^m$, such that
$$
\lim_{\|w\|\to 0}\frac{\|f(x_0+w)-f(x_0)-Aw\|}{\|w\|}=0. \tag{1}
$$ 
This unique linear functional $A$ in $(1)$ is called the differential of $f$ at $x_0$, and is denoted by $Df(x_0)$.*

If $\nu\in \mathbb R^d\smallsetminus\{0\}$ and $w=h\nu$, and $f$ is differentiable at $x=x_0$, then $(1)$ implies that
$$
\lim_{\|h\|\to 0}\frac{\|f(x_0+h\nu)-f(x_0)-hDf(x_0)\nu\|}{\lvert h\rvert}=0, 
$$ 
or, dividing numerator and denominator by $h$
$$
\lim_{\|h\|\to 0}\,\Big\|\,\frac{f(x_0+h\nu)-f(x_0)}{h}-Df(x_0)\nu\,\Big\|. \tag{**}
$$
Now $(*)$ and $(**)$ implies that
$$
D_\nu f(x_0)=Df(x_0)\nu.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $\lambda(t) = x_0+t v$. Then $D_v f(x_0) = (f \circ \lambda)'(0)$.

Since $f$ is differentiable, we can apply the chain rule to get
$(f \circ \lambda)'(0) = D(f \circ \lambda)(0) = Df(\lambda(0)) D \lambda(0) = Df(x_0) v$.

(You can find this many texts, for example in look at the commentary after Definition 3 in Section 6.4 of Marsden's "Elementary Classical Analysis".)